# UITableViewCell know which cell is clicked / selected

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I know that there is this method to detect which UITableViewCell is selected:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

}
```

But i don't want to know the selected row, i want to know what the content of the cell is and according to that i want to do something. So is there a way to tag a cell?
For better understanding, let's say i have four cells 1, 2, 3 and 4. When i reorder them and my order is 1, 4, 2, 3 and i want to show the value in another view, then it'd show me 2 instead of 4 when i select the second row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cab call

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method from your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` implementation to get the cell, like this:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ...
}
```

However, this is *not* the proper way of accessing, especially modifying, the table's content. Instead, you should access the *model* from which the table takes its information, and make all modifications there. This way the changes would "stick" when the current cell's visuals are scrolled off the screen and back.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to access or modify the content though, sorry for the misunderstanding, i just want to know which cell was selected so i can display the proper view.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways as far as my knowledge,

1) Access that cell by calling [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].
Now you can compare data of cell with your model. i.e. You can use NSPredicate to get index value of your selected row data in you model(from which you are filling table cell)

2) When ever you reorder your table row simply change your model as well. E.g. Row-4 becomes Row-2, reorder your model(probably ArrayList) by simply remove object from 4th position and add in 2nd position. So when ever you delete table row it will be same index number of your model data for that row.

3) You can tag each view. But this is code redundancy. You can achieve such thing with out doing so. Instead of this option i will go for 1st or 2nd (For my opinion 2nd option is best if use your model/Array for keeping record only.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the selected cell like this in didselect delegate method.

```
 UITableViewCell *lab = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *selectedCellLabelText = lab.textLabel.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can define a property of NSString in your second class to access the value corresponding to particular cell content, arrayData is your array in which your value is stored e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 then write this code in your first class :-

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    secondView.stringValue = [arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];    
}
```